# How do I view ONLY my projects along with their ids which are on Gitlab via a curl command?

Tags: git, gitlab

I am trying to use the Gitlab API to create a release, and was getting familiar with the basics. I have already generated the private token key, but am having trouble with using it properly. Right now, I cannot even list my projects along with its id.

I have used this :

`curl "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects?private_token=XXXX"`

But, I am only seeing a whole lot of data about a host of projects, that are not mine. How do I filter out, or get the data only related to my repo ?

Comment: It looks like you're calling the wrong api.  Maybe [this one](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#list-user-projects)?

Comment: @larsks, thanks for pointing me to the correct page. But, I am now seeing only this data: 

$ curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: xxxx" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/users/2189374/projects"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100     2  100     2    0     0      1      0  0:00:02  0:00:01  0:00:01     1[]

Comment: I've added an answer along with an example of calling the api with my own credentials. I'm using my username in that example, but it also works correctly with my numeric user id.

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if you're calling the wrong API.  The `/projects` endpoint returns a list of [all visible projects](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#list-all-projects).  To see just a list of projects owned by a particular user (e.g., you), you want the [list user projects](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#list-user-projects) api:

```
GET /users/:user_id/projects
```

For example, I can get a list of my projects like this:

```
curl -s -H "private-token: $token" https://gitlab.com/api/v4/users/larsks/projects
```

Which correctly returns a couple of projects from back when I was using gitlab for hosting.  The result looks something like:

```
[
  {
    "id": 123456,
    "description": "",
    "name": "kiwi",
    [...]
  },
  {
    "id": 654321,
    "description": "",
    "name": "sensormgr",
    [...]
  }
]
```

In your comment on the question, it looks as if you're getting an empty list in response:

```
[]
```

Do you own any projects? There certainly aren't any public projects associated with your gitlab account.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! You made it a bit more clear for me to understand the GItlab API commands. Also, I have all my projects as "Private", so would it not be visible? Are only public projects visible?